# Modify Existing HTML Table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I have an HTML table that I request from a webserver in C#.  I am then displaying the page in my aspx webform.  How can I add a prerequisite ***based on the course ID*** to the last column in the table *without hard-coding* the prerequisite?  Example of the table design is below.

```
<tr bgcolor="#E1E1CC">
   <td width="7%">003597</td>
   <td width="5%">01</td>
   <td width="1%">OPT</td>
   <td width="8%">MT H   </td>
   <td width="16%">2:00 pm - 2:50 pm  </td>
   <td width="17%">08/26/13 - 12/12/13</td>
   <td width="8%">
       <a href="http://www.mnsu.edu/registrar/building.html"target = _blank>
           <b>TR C124</b>
       </a>
   </td>
   <td width="19%">Staff</td>
   <td width="4%">22</td>
   <td width="4%">6</td>
   <td width="4%"><font color="#000000">Open</font></td>
   <td width="7%">
        <a href=Notes.asp?SpclNote=20143+003597+IT+100 target = _blank>
           <b>Notes</b>
        </a>
   </td>
</tr> 
<tr bgcolor="#E1E1CC">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%">M      </td>
    <td width="16%">10:00 am - 11:50 am</td>
    <td width="17%">08/26/13 - 12/09/13</td>
    <td width="8%">
        <a href="http://www.mnsu.edu/registrar/building.html"target = _blank>
            <b>WH 0119       </b>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td width="19%">Staff</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to append a column to a table

Comment: Yes that could work or else I could modify an existing column.

Comment: I can really think of any other simple way then modifying the from on a web-server to add the column other way will require you to use jquery to manipulate table

Comment: The requirement would be that this has to work dynamically, so if the table that I'm requesting changes, the Prerequisites column would change as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the page html as a string you could just insert your html into it.  Something like:

```
private void SetValue(string PageHtml, string ID, string TextToInsert)
{
    string html = PageHtml;
    string sMyHtmlToInsert = TextToInsert;
    int iSplitIndex = html.IndexOf(ID);
    iSplitIndex = html.IndexOf("{tag}",iSplitIndex);
    string sHtml1 = html.SubString(0, iSplitIndex);
    string sHtml2 = html.SubString(iSplitIndex);
    string sFinalHtml = sHtml1 + sMyHtmlToInsert + sHtml2;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with an if statement?  For example, if the row is equal to "00357", column = "IT 214"?

Comment: Yes you could search for the ID you are looking for, I'll edit the code above

Comment: Yes you could search for the ID you are looking for, I'll edit the code above.  I haven't tested the above code so you may have to play around with it a little.  Just replace {tag} with some html that signifies the point where you want to insert your TextToInsert

Comment: In your code example, if you wanted to set the value at <b>TR C124</b>  you could use:    iSplitIndex = html.IndexOf("<b>",iSplitIndex) + 3;  This would then set the insert location to just inside the <b> tag.  If you already have text there you may need to remove it first but if you haven't then you can just use the methodI've written above